# PHP PDO FetchAll vs Fetch

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I believe I am using the PDO fetch functions completely wrong. Here is what I am trying to do:

Query a row, get the results, use a helper function to process the results into an array.

Query

```
function userName($db){
  $q = $db->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE id = :user");
  $q->bindParam(":user", $user);
  $q->execute();
  $qr = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if ($qr->rowCount() > 0){
    foreach($qr as $row){
      $names[$row['id']] = buildArray($row);
    }
  return $names;
  }
}
```

My custom array building function

```
function buildArray($row){
 $usernames = array();
 if(isset($row['id'])) $usernames['id'] = $row['id'];
 if(isset($row['name'])) $usernames['name'] = $row['name'];
}
```

I'm actually getting exactly what I want from this, but when I echo inbetween I see that things are looping 3 times instead of once. I think I am misusing fetchAll.

Any help appreciated

Comment: How many entries do you fetch? Where do you `echo`?

Comment: `buildArray()` has no `return` statement

Comment: What do you mean by looping 3 times? The only loop is `foreach($qr as $row)`. Where do you see other loops?

Comment: Just think **You** and not the stupid computer would have to do things. What would you do?

Comment: @DOCASAREL if I echo in the If statement, I see 2 echoes (just pretend I have two similar Ids). If I echo in the foreach, I see 6 echoes. So 2x3=6 for some reason the loop is happening 3 times. Also please don't worry about the little things here, I wrote this as an eg.

Comment: The loop happens 1 time for each row returned. There are 2 if statements, so you get 2 echoes there. So you're just counting all the cells, there's no extra looping being done.

Comment: I think Barmar nailed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to build a new array, there's not much point in having `fetchAll()` build an array. Write your own `fetch()` loop:

```
function userName($db){
    $q = $db->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE id = :user");
    $q->bindParam(":user", $user);
    $q->execute();
    $names = array();
    while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $names[$row['id']] = $row;
    }
    return $names;
}
```

There's also no need for `buildArray()`, since `$row` is already the associative array you want.

Comment: Brilliant thanks... now why can I not return $names? It says it is undefined (it's in a function). I tried to define it at the start of the function $names; and return $names outside of the while loop...

Comment: I'd need to see your code, I can't tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Ya sorry, it was complaining when it didn't find a result. So I placed the while loop in an if rowCount()>0 etc.. All good

Comment: There's no need for that `if`. If there are no rows, the loop will finish immediately.

Comment: You need to initialize the variable to an empty array before the loop.

Comment: @mickmackusa That was an editing mistake. I had originally just written the loop. Then I copied the rest of the function around it, and forgot to remove `fetchAll()`. This wouldn't be the first time I wrote a "Do X instead of Y" answer and then forgot to actually change the code as recommended. :)